# Page redirection not working in angularjs using window.location.href

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am coding a page where after the user has entered the data in input fields, the data will be validated with an ajax request. After the data has been validated the page must be redirected to another page.

The below code is not working :

```
                $scope.validateUser = function() {

                    username = $scope.username;
                    password = $scope.password;

                    if ( username === "nrvarun89") {
                        console.log(username+" "+password+" path is :"+window.location.href);
                        window.location.href = "http://localhost/b2c-webadmin/index/";
                        console.log(username+" "+password+" new path is :"+window.location);
                    }
                };
```

Comment: Do state why the code is not working, otherwise it's much harder to help you.

Comment: @Claies the page is not getting redirected

Comment: this code doesn't make sense.  where is the call to this `$scope.validateUser` coming from? where is `$scope.username` and `$scope.password` being set? why are you taking in a parameter and then overwriting it's value as the first statement in the function?  does the `if` block ever actually execute?

Comment: @Claies the if block does get executed i have tried checking it with a window.alert()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using anuglarjs make use of the $window service (best practice):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

This should work:

`$window.location.href`

(See this for reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)